# How to receive props in child component in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, strapi, nuxtjs3

I have searched a lot of places online but can't seem to find a clear and straight to the point answer anywhere.
Given this loop in a parent component to out a list of child component, I am sending an object as props to a child component like this

```
<div v-for="review in reviews">
  <ReviewsReview v:bind={review} :key="venuceReview.id" />
</div>
```

Each `review Object` will be in this format

```
{
 "_id": "58c03ac18060197ca0b52d51",
 "author":  3,
 "user":  2,
 "comment": "I tried this place last week and it was incredible! Amazing selection of local and imported brews and the food is to die for! ",
 "score": 5,
 "date": "2017-03-08T17:09:21.627Z"
}
```

My question is how do I retrieve the props in the child component using `defineProps()` here:

```
<script setup>
import ReviewStyles from "./review.module.css"

const props = defineProps()
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the parent component, you pass some values to the child component, using a colon followed by the name you want to access with in the child component.

On the parent component, say `pages/index.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="review in reviews">
      <SingleReview :review="review" :key="review._id" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

In this case, we pass each `review` object to the child with the name `review`.

On the child component named `components/singleReview.vue`:

```js
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  review: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
});
const { review } = props;
</script>
```

And we access each `review` prop in the child component using the same name.

See a working [replication](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-9gzh9j)

Comment: Easy and straight to the point. Thank you very much.